# drupal8 login password forget

Tags: command-line, drupal, cms

I had install drupal 8 on my ubuntu 16.04 bt username or password have forget for login. email id also show not recognized. how to find user name or password

Comment: please help me any one for found user name and password, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to update as follow, this should update admin password to passpass

```
update users_field_data set pass='$S$EplZajxeAARcsuUmCMaXmM42DZmgxfp59psLWH5rOakPZqPwGpSQ' where uid=1;
```